# Wrap a React Router Routes with an Auth Component inside a Switch

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I currently have a set of routes which I want to be accessible only if the user is having a certain user role, let's say an Admin role.

I want these routes to be wrapped in a component, say `Auth`, which will check the user's role against the required roles.

```
<Switch>
  <Auth roles={['user']}>
     <Route exact path="/repos/" component={Repos} />
     <Route exact path="/repos/:repo" component={Repo} />
  </Auth>
  <Auth roles={['admin']}>
     <Route exact path="/repos/:repo/settings" component={RepoSettings} />
  </Auth>
</Switch>
```

And `Auth` is implmented like this,

```
const AuthWrapper = ({ children, roles, ...props }) => {
  if (Authenticator(roles)) {
    return React.Children.map(
        children,
        (child, i) => (React.cloneElement(child, {
            key: i, ...props,
        })),
    );
  }

  return null;
};
```

But the problem is, both the `Repos` and `Repo` components get rendered when I go to `/repos/` or `/repos/somerepo`!

Finally how it is rendered is like this,

[image: Finally how it is rendered is like this]

Here's a playground with my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/oo7lzpww6q

Answer (score 2):

**Updated answer:**

When rendering the `Routes` using `React.cloneElement`, the `exact` prop is being assigned a value of `true`.  This is causing the router to match incorrectly.  If you don't need the `key` prop added to each `Route`, you should be able to resolve this by simply returning the children.

---

**Original answer:**

According to the [docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Switch.md):

> All children of a Switch should be Route or Redirect elements.

You could make a component that wraps a route, takes the roles prop and handles the authentication.

`<PrivateRoute exact path='/repos/:repo/settings' roles={['admin']} component={RepoSettings} />`

There's an elaborated example of this in the [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow).

Comment: Oh! In the same way, can't I make a component that wraps several routes? @Brian

Comment: I see even the code in example finally have the wrapper component as the immediate child of `Switch` https://i.imgur.com/sUGuW2O.png

Comment: @MilinduSanojKumarage The wrapper component returns a Route or null, so does not conflict with the spec that the Switch only contain Routes. 

You can have Routes within a component but they are registered globally with the Router.

Comment: If you check the screenshot here https://i.imgur.com/sUGuW2O.png , the immediate child of `Switch` is not `Route` but `PrivateRoute`.  ( you can inspect and see with React Dev Tools  https://codesandbox.io/s/v10mrlomk0 here ) 
But it works here. I want to do the same thing, I just want to return more than one route, that's the difference. I'm confused :/

Comment: I've updated the answer - it was actually an issue with the way cloneElement was rendering the Route element, assigning a value to `exact`.